# Grid Maui loses cells when I insert a new row

Tags: c#, .net, maui

### Context

I have a page with a Grid component for product list selected, when the user adds a product, the product are added to the Grid with a new Row.

In the same page, I have a Button that adds the product to the grid

The headers of the Grid are added in the XAML file

```xml
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="0.1*,0.4*,0.1*,0.25*" x:Name="gridData"Grid.Row="4" ColumnSpacing="1">
      <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <BoxView Color="Red" />
      <Label Text="#"HorizontalOptions="Center"VerticalOptions="Center" />
      <BoxView Color="Red" Grid.Column="1"/>
      <Label Text="Descripción" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
      <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Color="Red"/>
      <Label Text="Cant." Grid.Column="2" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
      <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="3" Color="Red" />
      <Label Text="Total" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Headers of grid in run time:

[image: Headers of grid in run time]

### The issue

When added, the first product in the Grid loses the last two cells of headers:

[image: Grid loses cells in run time]

My code for adding the new row is this:

```cs
RowDefinition row = new RowDefinition();
row.Height = 50;
gridData.AddRowDefinition(row);
gridData.Add(new BoxView
{
    Color = color
}, 0, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new Label
{
    Text = "2",
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = Colors.Black
}, 0, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new BoxView
{
    Color = color
}, 1, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new Label
{
    Text = "Desc 2",
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = Colors.Black
}, 1, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new BoxView
{
    Color = color
}, 2, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new Label
{
    Text = "1",
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = Colors.Black
}, 2, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new BoxView
{
    Color = color
}, 3, count_rows);
gridData.Add(new Label
{
    Text = "$ 132.40",
    HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
    TextColor = Colors.Black
}, 3, count_rows);
count_rows++;
```

Note: My code is using hard code data.

How can i fix this issue? or how do I add the headers correctly?

Thanks

Comment: why not using a CollectionView instead of the Grid ?

Comment: Thanks,I implemented the CollectionView.